# How to add data in tables in doc file using JWord

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am creating a multifile converter app , in which user can convert the excel sheet in different  format like pdf and word file(.doc) , i using apache  POI to read the data from excel sheet , and using JWord library(https://www.independentsoft.de/jword/) to create a word file , word file is created succesfully but i am not able to add data in table wise ,i want to add data in word file like excel sheet , i little confused not able to achieve that.

Table creation is given on the Jword documentation but i am not able to map with excel data anyone help me

my method in which word file is generated

```
void generateWordFile() throws Exception{
    try
    {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MultiFileCon");

        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(this, "created dir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        // System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        Log.d("DATE", formatter.format(date) + ".pdf");

        File docfile = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), formatter.format(date) + ".doc");

        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new 
File(PathUtil.getPath(this, uriforExcel)));
        // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
        HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);




        // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
        HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // To iterate over the rows
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
        //We will create output PDF document objects at this point
        Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, new FileOutputStream(docfile));
        iText_xls_2_pdf.open();
        //we have two columns in the Excel sheet, so we create a PDF table with two columns
        //Note: There are ways to make this dynamic in nature, if you want to.
        PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(7);
        //We will use the object below to dynamically add new data to the table
        PdfPCell table_cell;


        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                    //you need to add more code here based on
                    //your requirement / transformations
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                        table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                        Log.d("DOL", cell.getStringCellValue());



                        datatobe.append(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\n");


                        //feel free to move the code below to suit to your needs
                        my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                        break;
                }
                //next line
            }

            // Log.d("DOL", "Convert_to_PDF: "+datatobe);

        }
        //Finally add the table to PDF document
        iText_xls_2_pdf.add(my_table);
        iText_xls_2_pdf.close();
        //we created our pdf file..
        input_document.close();


        WordDocument doc = new WordDocument();

        Run run = new Run();
        run.addText(datatobe.toString());

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.add(run);





        doc.getBody().add(paragraph);

        doc.save(docfile.getAbsolutePath(), true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```